# How to find a specific string?

Tags: php

```php
$linkarray = [];
$sukses = 'its a user';
$gagal = 'its a media';


foreach ($linkarray as $url) {
  $links = $url->full_url;

  if(...) { // for this section
    echo $links.$sukses;
  }else{
    echo $links.$gagal;
  }
}
```

there is 2 different output from the ***$links*** that gives url
**1.**`https://siteexample.com/user/1234/`
**2.**`https://siteexample.com/media/1234/`

and now, for the `if(...)` , how to match if the output shows **/user/** in the url then `echo $links.$sukses;` 
but if the output shows **/media/** in the url then `echo $links.$gagal;`

ive tried using `strpos()` but it work only if the output is separated using space  `https://siteexample.com /user/ 1234/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perfectly use the strpos or stripos for this case, it is not limited that you need to use spaces:

```php
if( strpos($url->full_url, 'user') !== false ) 
{
    echo $links.$sukses;
}
```

Or if you want to make sure it match /user/ its also possible to match that

```php
if( strpos($url->full_url, '/user/') !== false ) 
{
    echo $links.$sukses;
}
```

Example with strpos or case insensitive stripos:
https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/bzjm

On the PHP docs there is also a good explanation: 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php